# Multiply a specific value with a series of columns based on a Condition in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have data of a certain country that gives the certain age group population in a time series. I am trying to multiply the number of the female population with `-1` to display it on the other side of the pyramid graph. I have achieved that for one year i.e 1960 (see code below). Now I want to achieve the same results for all the columns from 1960-2020

`PakPopulation.loc[PakPopulation['Gender']=="Female",['1960']]=PakPopulation['1960'].apply(lambda x:-x)`

I have also tried the following solution but no luck:

```
PakPopulation.loc[PakPopulation['Gender']=="Female",[:,['1960':'2019']]=PakPopulation[:,['1960':'2019']].apply(lambda x:-x)
```

Schema:

| Country | Age Group | Gender | 1960 | 1961 | 1962 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ | 0-4 | Male | 5880k | 5887k | 6998k |
| XYZ | 0-4 | Female | 5980k | 6887k | 7998k |

Comment: Use: `PakPopulation.iloc[:, 3: 4 + 2019 -1960].apply(lambda x:-x)`? or simply `-PakPopulation.iloc[:, 3: 4 + 2019 -1960]`

Comment: However I am surprise how your code for `1960` is not throwing an error. On the LHS, you are only selecting row with `Gender = Female` while on RHS you are having all the rows, hence the length will not match.

Comment: On the LHS its selecting all the rows of 1960 where Gender==Female and on the RHS it is multiplying them with -1

Comment: LHS and RHS are of different length, but somehow pandas is able to match index and then assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a list of years and use that list as part of your selection:

```py
import pandas as pd

PakPopulation = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country': {0: 'XYZ', 1: 'ABC'},
    'Age Group': {0: '0-4', 1: '0-4'},
    'Gender': {0: 'Male', 1: 'Female'},
    '1960': {0: 5880, 1: 5980},
    '1961': {0: 5887, 1: 6887},
    '1962': {0: 6998, 1: 7998},
})

start_year = 1960
end_year = 1962
years_lst = list(map(str, range(start_year, end_year + 1)))
PakPopulation.loc[PakPopulation['Gender'] == "Female", years_lst] = \
    PakPopulation[years_lst].apply(lambda x: -x)

print(PakPopulation)
```

Output:

```
  Country Age Group  Gender  1960  1961  1962
0     XYZ       0-4    Male  5880  5887  6998
1     ABC       0-4  Female -5980 -6887 -7998
```